# Error with pm list packages in Android adb shell

Tags: android, adb, root

I tried running this command `pm list packages > package.txt` in adb shell in order to save all installed packages in a text file but I get the following saved in the txt file:

cmd: Failure calling service package: Failed transaction (2147483646)

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

my similar case is:

```
 adb shell su -c pm list packages -f
cmd: Failure calling service package: Failed transaction (2147483646)
```

added `-t` for shell:

```
 adb shell -t su -c pm list packages -f
package:/system/priv-app/OemDmTrigger/OemDmTrigger.apk=com.google.omadm.trigger
...
```

worked.

Note:

(get from `adb --help`) related syntax:

- adb

  - shell

    - -t: allocate a pty if on a tty (-tt: force pty allocation)

Answer (score 0):

Just output it to a path that has no permission/root issues, like:

> pm list packages -f > /data/local/tmp/packages.txt